# What happens if event occurs again when the first is not finished handling

Tags: c#, event-handling, serial-port

My Question is about the `DataReceived` event from an `System.IO.SerialPort`. I have a method which gets called when that event occurs. I read the Data with `myPort.ReadExisting`, process it and save it. If I get a specific character the data up to that point is interpreted as command and another event is triggered.

My question is, what happens if I'm in the middle of processing the received Data and new data comes? Is the new instances of the method waiting for the old to finish? If not it could result in a conflict because both instances of that method use the same variables. Am I wrong in the concept of event handling or is there an elegant way to deal with that.

My code is running fine and my results are as expected, but my data processing is not that sophisticated. I just want to understand this issue und avoid getting problems in the future.
My Code example would be this:

```
private void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{

        SerialPort port = (SerialPort)sender;
        int index = m_ports.FindIndex(p => p.PortName == port.PortName);
        string tmpData;
        m_currentData[index] += tmpData = port.ReadExisting();
        Console.WriteLine(tmpData);

        string currentData = m_currentData[index];
        string currentOrder = "";
        while (currentData.Contains(orderEndChar))
        {
            int endCharLocation = currentData.IndexOf(orderEndChar);
            currentOrder = currentData.Substring(0, endCharLocation);
            currentData = currentData.Substring(endCharLocation + 1);
            orderEvent.gotOrder(currentOrder);
            //orderEvent.gotOrder(new EventArgs());
        }
        m_currentData[index] = currentData;

}
```

The lists are because I want it to work with multiple Ports from where I can get commands.

Comment: You can test this yourself by calling `Console.WriteLine` at the start and end of your method.

Comment: Related post. Please see if it helps - [IO operation aborted error thrown while reading serial port](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21305392/465053)

Comment: How about fire up a new thread for every incomming data so no one has to wait?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what your concern is, but the I/O interrupt won't cause your program to just jump out of whatever method it's in; the event would be queued up for processing on the message loop.

Comment: @DamoV That's a crazy idea.

Comment: @rory.ap - IO events don't happen on (wait for) the message loop.

Comment: @bommelding -- I know that, but the event handlers do, don't they?  The event handlers should all be running on the main thread, right?

Comment: No, eventhandlers run on the thread that raised the event.

Comment: @spender Nah. You could easily set a Max-Thread Count which would be idealy CPU Cores + 1 and there ya go.Or am I missing something? OK! According to tomassino's answer, the idea with multi-threads is useless. BUT it could work ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SerialPort.DataReceived is invoked on secondary thread.

Read here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx


 So if you have many SerialPort instances listening, it may happen that there will be more that one `Port_DataReceived` methods running at the same time. But do not be afraid of local variables, as they live only in specific method call. Therefore 3 different threads running the same method will initiate 3 different local variables, even if their name is the same. But be careful with global variables.


Since `Port_DataReceived` is synchronous, the next event invocation **on the same** `SerialPort` **object** will wait so these invocations are performed one by one.

Comment: so synchronous means that a method will not get called again from one object if its still running. Lets say COM1 port emits datareceived and it gets handled, then new data arrives. Will the COM1 port wait with emitting the datareceived event or is the handler waiting with calling the method? So the datareceived events get somehow queued internally?

Comment: Yes, queuing (if any) is implemented internally on `SerialPort` side or maybe more deep in protocol level.

Answer (score 1):

So, if you suspect that your producer might run faster than your consumer, you should decouple the two through the use of a queue.

All your producer has to do is push the data it receives into a (thread-safe) queue... a quick operation that will not overrun.

All the consumer has to do is read from the queue, at it's own speed.

[TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) offers the [`BufferBlock<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160414(v=vs.110).aspx) class which might serve as a handy queue for such a producer/consumer relationship.

You might choose to dig a bit deeper into dataflow. It's perfect for producer/consumer stuff in an async world.

Start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-messages-to-and-read-messages-from-a-dataflow-block